# Refreshing canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a question about refreshing canvas. There is .Refresh() or .Clear() in WinForms.But what about WPF?

I watched some methods how to do it, but it didn't help me at all.

The situation is that my canvas contains textBox and Button. When I click button I can draw some ellipses.

And I need to clear these ellipses after my every click on button but ***without clearing textBox and Button from this Canvas***!

My WPF Xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="draw.CreateEllipse"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Create" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="Create" Closed="Create_Closed">
<Canvas Name="can" Background="White" MouseDown="can_MouseDown">
    <TextBox Name="txbNumber" Height="34" Canvas.Left="797" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" Canvas.Top="76" Width="209" FontSize="18"/>
    <Button Name="btnCreate" Content="Create" Canvas.Left="797" Canvas.Top="130" Width="209" Height="66" FontSize="18" Click="btnCreate_Click"/>
</Canvas>
```

My C# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace draw
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для CreateGraph.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Create : Window
{
    public Create()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int n, i;
    Ellipse[] v;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    SolidColorBrush solidcolor = new SolidColorBrush();
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        n = Convert.ToInt16(txbNumber.Text);
        v = new Ellipse[n];

        //can.Children.Clear();
    }


    private void Create_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    private void can_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        solidcolor.Color = Colors.Transparent;


        //Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            v[i] = new Ellipse();
            mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.Transparent;
            v[i].Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            v[i].StrokeThickness = 2;
            v[i].Stroke = Brushes.Black;

            v[i].Width = 75;
            v[i].Height = 75;

            v[i].Margin = new Thickness(e.GetPosition(can).X, e.GetPosition(can).Y, 0, 0);
            can.Children.Add(v[i]);
        }
        if (n <= 0)
            return;
        n--;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Just remove the ellipse from the canvas children...

Comment: Iterate through the elements and only remove if they are ellipses.

Comment: I tried to add this :
if (can.Children.Contains(Ellipse)=true)
            {
                can.Children.Clear();
            }
but there is a mistake

Comment: The mistake is that if the children contains an ellipse, you are clearing out the children, all of them, not just the ellipse. You need to remove individual elements from the children, not clear it out entirely.

Comment: Try instead something like `foreach (Ellipse ellipse in can.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList()) can.Children.Remove(ellipse);`

Answer (score 1):

you can separate your elements with this code:

```
var can2 = can.Children.OfType<Ellipse>();
```

above code select all of Ellipses in your Canvas "can".
and you can remove them from your Canvas Like this:

```
foreach (var element in can2)
{
    can.Children.Remove(element);
}
```

Now you have no ellipse in your Canvas.

Hope this helps you.